# В чем смысл OnStart, когда все можно запихать в конструктор службы?

Tags: c#, .net, service

На мой взгляд, `OnStart` нужен для какой-то инициализации.

Зачем нужен метод `OnStart`, когда все можно добавить в конструктор службы?

Comment: для того и нужен, чтобы не пихать все в конструктор :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Запуск службы в отдельном процессе происходит так:

**Сначала запускается процесс.** Процесс считается запущенным, когда вызван метод [`ServiceBase.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.run(v=vs.110).aspx)

Если процесс долго не запускается (тайм-аут там стоит 3 или 5 секунд) - винда прекращает запуск службы и переводит службу в режим останова. При этом не отрабатывает автоматический перезапуск, а в системных логах - невнятная ошибка.

Также, пока процесс не запущен, диспетчер служб не имеет возможности выдавать службе никаких команд - что с точки зрения администратора может выглядеть как крайняя степень глючности.

**Потом запускается служба.** Служба считается запущенной когда отработал метод `OnStart`. Этого события система ждет дольше - тайм-аут по умолчанию там 30 секунд. Кроме того, всегда можно запросить дополнительное время с помощью метода [RequestAdditionalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Пока служба запускается - она находится в состоянии, которое так и называется - "Запускается". Если служба не успела или не смогла запуститься - это событие отрабатывается системой куда адекватнее.

---

Поэтому, в конструкторе службы, также как и в методе Main, следует делать только те действия, которые  могут быть сделаны *быстро*. Для долгих действий надо использовать `OnStart`. А очень долгие - надо выносить в отдельный поток и предусматривать прерывание их на середине.

Также следует помнить, что *внезапно долгим* может оказаться любой сетевой запрос, обращение к СУБД или к файлу по сетевому пути - причем их тайм-ауты по умолчанию превышают тайм-аут ожидания запуска процесса. Ни одно из этих действий нельзя делать в конструкторе.

Answer (score 5):

Ох, давно дело было.
Если мне память не изменяет, то с `OnStart` начинается непосредственное выполнение службой действий, какие тебе нужны. А конструктор он для инициализации именно. Так же `OnStart` способен принять аргументы, которые могут сконфигурировать выполнение службы.
Прошу прощения за неточность, но так же `OnStart` является методом жизненного цикла, и по логике должен вызываться в самый подходящий момент для запуска службы. Есть ли в этом разница с конструктором или нет - не могу с уверенностью сказать, но жизненный цикл вообще для таких вещей и служит.

**UPD:** Конструктор службы вызывается единожды при иницализации, в дальнейшем служба может быть запущена с вызовом `OnStart`, остановлена с помощью `OnStop` и еще пара методов для рабы с приостановкой `OnPause` и `OnContinue`. Разница между конструктором и `OnStart` проявляется так же в том, что конструктор не вызывается после повторного запуска, сразу же вызывается метод `OnStart`, который должен инициализировать необходимые для работы ресурсы и запустить производимые службой действия.

Вот тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase(v=vs.110).aspx все очень хорошо описано.

Comment: Ну, повторный вызов OnStart возможен только если в одном процессе две службы. Иначе сразу же после OnStop происходит завершение процесса.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, "При первом вызове команды запуска для службы исполняемый файл вызывает конструктор класса, производного от класса ServiceBase.Сразу после выполнения конструктора вызывается метод OnStart, обеспечивающий обработку команд.После первой загрузки службы повторно конструктор не выполняется, и обработку, выполняемую конструктором, необходимо отделять от обработки, выполняемой методом OnStart.Любые ресурсы, освобождаемые методом OnStop, должны быть созданы методом OnStart."

Comment: Вы процитировали описание общего случая. Который наступает если другая служба "держит" процесс "в живых" пока первую перезапускают.

Comment: Ну а вы описали частный случай.Наиболее общим является тот, при котором служба управляется диспетчером.

Comment: Я описал *наиболее частый* случай. Вот ни разу за 8 лет практики не видел чтобы две службы сидели на одном процессе...